# why java updating query is not working?

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I am using a MS Access database and I finalize insert and delete query which are working perfect, but why update query is not working please help?

code for insert:

```
try {
    ps=oon.prepareStatement("insert into Student(Studentid,Studentname,Age,Contactno, Degreeprogram)values(?,?,?,?,?)");
    ps.setString(1,jTextField1.getText());
    ps.setString(2,jTextField2.getText());
    ps.setString(3,jTextField3.getText());
    ps.setString(4,jTextField4.getText());
    ps.setString(5,jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted");
    ps.executeQuery();

} catch(Exception ex){}
```

and delete:

```
try {
    ps=oon.prepareStatement("DELETE from Student WHERE Studentid=?");
    ps.setString(1, jTextField5.getText());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");
    ps.executeQuery();

} catch(Exception ex){}
```

Update code (from comment):

```
try{ 
   ps=oon.prepareStatement("UPDATE Student set Studentid=?,Studentname=?,age=?,Contactno=?,Degreeprogram=? WHERE Studentid="+Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())); 
   ps.setString(2, jTextField2.getText()); 
   ps.setString(3, jTextField3.getText()); 
   ps.setString(4, jTextField4.getText()); 
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update"); ps.executeQuery(); 
   // TODO add your handling code here: 
}
```

Comment: You are throwing away your `Exception ex`. Do not do that, the ifnormation could very well be there. And why are you catching the full `Exception` anyway? Always catch a subclass.

Comment: i am doing these coding on jframe.. these queries on insert and delete button but update query is not working ?

Comment: this is code for update but not working                             try{
   
       ps=oon.prepareStatement("UPDATE Student set Studentid=?,Studentname=?,age=?,Contactno=?,Degreeprogram=? WHERE Studentid="+Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()));
        ps.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
        ps.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
        ps.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update");
        ps.executeQuery();
         // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

Comment: So, your update query doesn't work correctly. And what you're showing us are the insert and delete queries, which work fine. So we have to guess what your update query does and what the problem is.

Comment: So we are not interested in your insert or delete, where is Update???

Comment: ps.setString(2): don't you think the first parameter has to be defined too? And the fifth one? Why don't you read the stack trace of the exception you get? It would have told you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting parameters 1 and 5, so most likely it is complaining about parameter 1 and/or 5 not being set. You shouldn't swallow exceptions like you are doing, you should either let the exception bubble/propagate to a layer that can either handle the exception, or at minimum print or log the exception if the application cannot (or doesn't want to) take corrective actions.

Also, I'd strongly suggest to replace your WHERE clause `WHERE Studentid="+Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())` with `WHERE Studentid=?` and add `ps.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()))`.

Comment: Actually, he/she should even let the exception propagate, or wrap it into another one and throw it. A failed update statement should generally not let the program continue as if everything went fine.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed, however looking at the code I had the feeling this might have been a simple student assignment and I didn't want to overcomplicate it. I amended my answer.